# AngularJS - Add function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just getting started with AngularJS. I'm coming from backend development, so this JavaScript is confusing for me. I followed the AngularJS tutorial and got the basics working.

I have a "record-list.component.js" file (Name derived from the AngularJS demo) which has a function to download data:

```
angular.module('recordList').component('recordList', {
templateUrl: 'record-list/record-list.template.html',
controller: function RecordListController($http) {
    var self = this;
    // self.orderProp = 'age';
    $http.get('http://X/camera/record/1/').then(function(response) {
        self.recordings = response.data;
    });
}
})
```

This all works fine. However, I want to add another function that will call a URL so the backend can perform some magic. So I tried something like this:

```
angular.module('recordList').component('recordList', {
templateUrl: 'record-list/record-list.template.html',
controller: function RecordListController($http) {
    var self = this;
    // self.orderProp = 'age';
    $http.get('http://blackvue.tozz.nl/camera/record/1/').then(function(response) {
        self.recordings = response.data;
    });
}
function DownloadFileController($file) {
    $window.alert("Hi: " + $file);
}
})
```

This does not work. I tried a variety, such as controller: function, but nothing seems to work. Can someone point me into the good direction?

Comment: you need shift DownloadFileController function inside the controller if you want call this fn from html. Remeber to add on controller scope the function

Comment: In fact as he is using `component` the method should be inside the controller and the function should be declared as: `this.DownloadFileController = function ($file) ...`. But this is only necessary if he wants to use it from the html with `ctrl.DownloadFileController`.

Answer (score 0):

@Luiz Carlos his answer was correct! I got it working with the following code:

```
angular.module('recordList').component('recordList', {
templateUrl: 'record-list/record-list.template.html',
controller: function RecordListController($http) {
    var self = this;
    // self.orderProp = 'age';
    $http.get('http://X/camera/record/1/').then(function(response) {
        self.recordings = response.data;
    });

    this.DownloadFileController = function ($file) {
        window.alert("Hi!");
    }
  }
})
```

And in HTML I can do:

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.DownloadFileController()">Test</button>
```

Thanks!